# setting repeated field in protobuf using reflection

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message similar to this:

```
message foo {
   repeated double values = 1;
}
```

I am using reflection (as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection)) to set the values like this in my C++ code

```
auto desc = protoMsg.GetDescription();
auto refl = protoMsg.GetReflection();
auto fd = desc->FindFieldByNumber(1); // run time value

assert(fd->is_repeated());
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
   refl->SetRepeatedDouble(&protoMsg, fd, i, vect[i]);
```

My application is crashing inside `SetRepeatedDouble` function. Has anyone tried to do something like this before? (set values using reflection? Note that I have to use reflection due to dynamic nature of my application. I have simplified above code slightly not to do that for now)

Also any tips on how to possible debug this are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetRepeatedDouble()` overwrites an already-present element of the array. For your code to work, the repeated field must already have a size at least equal to `vect.size()`, otherwise you are overrunning the array, which would indeed cause a crash (or worse). If you started with an empty message instance, then you need to **add** the values instead of setting them, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
    refl->AddDouble(&protoMsg, fd, vect[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is slightly non intuitive though. The documentations says something like:
- Possible sources of errors:

- A Get*() or Set*() method for singular fields is called on a repeated field.

- GetRepeated*(), SetRepeated*(), or Add*() is called on a non-repeated field.